# Rspec - You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller - I've already tried the common suggestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, authlogic

I know this question has been replied many times, but the existing answers are not resolving my issue.

I want to run my rspec tests for the controllers. I need to authenticate the user through Authlogic.

As many of you said (in other similar questions), I added to the **spec_helper.rb** file:

```
require "authlogic/test_case"
include Authlogic::TestCase
```

and **activate_authlogic** in the before each in **my events_controller_spec.rb**:

```
...
  before :each do
    activate_authlogic
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    UserSession.create(user)
  end
...
```

but running the rspec, I get always the infamous error message:

```
Failure/Error: UserSession.create(user)
     Authlogic::Session::Activation::NotActivatedError:
       You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects
```

Can you see what's wrong on it ?

Any suggestions are really welcome.

Thanks!

ps.

Versions used:
- rails 3.2
- rspec (2.11.0)
- rspec-core (2.11.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries I've found more that one issues:

- the user created by FactoryGirl was not a valid user
- instead of "before :each" sometimes I tried "before :all", and that added noise to my bug fixing

Sorry for the "not so useful" question :)

Answer (score 4):

try using `setup :activate_authlogic` or `Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)` instead of `activate_authlogic`, maybe it will help

Comment: Thanks Shamir, but it doesn't work. I think the first one is good if you use the unit test.
I've tried Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self), but I get "undefined method `cookie_jar' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: Debugging the code, I see that activate_authlogic return nil, looking at the Authlogic docs it should return something not nil. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand if you have found a solution, but here is the code I use to my Rspec controllers. You can catch the error of non-valid user before session creation !

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
def log_in(user)
  user.should_not be_nil
  session = UserSession.create!(user, false)
  session.should be_valid
  session.save
end
```

spec/controllers/...

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'authlogic/test_case'

describe xxxController do
  setup :activate_authlogic

  context "user logged" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
      log_in(@user)
    end
  end
end
```